# Making a d3 chart reactive (v5)

Tags: d3.js, charts, responsive-design, responsive

I'm new to d3.js and am trying to make a reactive chart based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/erikvullings/51cc5332439939f1f292), inside a UIKIT container. I have tried adjusting the width to the container using

```
d3.select("#chart").node().getBoundingClientRect().width
```

and also adjusting the viewBox aspect ratio of the svg using

```
  <div id="chart" class="uk-block-muted uk-margin-top"><svg width="960" height="500" viewBox="0 0 960 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"></div>
```

However it doesn't work and always cuts off the chart. Where am I going wrong? What is the best way to do this?

```html
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart" class=class="uk-block-muted uk-margin-top"> <svg class="chart"></svg> </div>
  <script>

  var data = {
  labels: [
    'Cornwall & Iles of Scilly', 'Isle of Wight', 'Cumbria',
    'Dorset', 'Norfolk', 'Devon', 'Bournemouth'
  ],
  series: [
    {
      label: 'Week ending 5 July',
      values: [1.4, 2.1, 3.6, 1.1, 1.6, 0.4, 1]
    },
    {
      label: 'Week ending 2 August',
      values: [3.3, 0, 8.2, 0.8, 2.1, 1.5, 2]
    },
  ]
};

var chartWidth       = d3.select("#chart").node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
    barHeight        = 20,
    groupHeight      = barHeight * data.series.length,
    gapBetweenGroups = 10,
    spaceForLabels   = 150,
    spaceForLegend   = 180;

// Zip the series data together (first values, second values, etc.)
var zippedData = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.labels.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<data.series.length; j++) {
    zippedData.push(data.series[j].values[i]);
  }
}

console.log(zippedData);
// Color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["#16A085", "#33435C"]);
var chartHeight = barHeight * zippedData.length + gapBetweenGroups * data.labels.length;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(zippedData)])
    .range([0, chartWidth]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([chartHeight + gapBetweenGroups, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .tickFormat('')
    .tickSize(0);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d){
return d;
});

// Specify the chart area and dimensions
var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", spaceForLabels + chartWidth + spaceForLegend)
    .attr("height", chartHeight +30);

   // console.log(chartHeight);

// Create bars
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(zippedData)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
      return "translate(" + spaceForLabels + "," + (i * barHeight + gapBetweenGroups * (0.5 + Math.floor(i/data.series.length))) + ")";
    });

// Create rectangles of the correct width
bar.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i % data.series.length); })
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; })
    .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

// Draw labels
bar.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return - 10; })
    .attr("y", groupHeight / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d,i) {
      if (i % data.series.length === 0)
        return data.labels[Math.floor(i/data.series.length)];
      else
        return ""});

chart.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + spaceForLabels + ", " + -gapBetweenGroups/2 + ")")
      .call(yAxis);

 chart.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + spaceForLabels + "," + chartHeight + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

// Draw legend
var legendRectSize = 18,
    legendSpacing  = 4;

var legend = chart.selectAll('.legend')
    .data(data.series)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
        var offset = -gapBetweenGroups/2;
        var horz = spaceForLabels + chartWidth + 40 - legendRectSize;
        var vert = i * height - offset;
        return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';
    });

legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', function (d, i) { return color(i); })
    .style('stroke', function (d, i) { return color(i); });

legend.append('text')
    .attr('class', 'legend')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function (d) { return d.label; });

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the full width of the svg and then not accounting for the legend and label when setting the data range. I just tested this in a JSFiddle and the bars seem to resize correctly when accounting for these two variables.

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(zippedData)])
    .range([0, chartWidth - spaceForLegend - spaceForLabels]);
```

Comment: thanks - it's made it better but the bottom is still cut off in smaller windows and the legend vanishes off screen so I can't get it fully functional